# How do I Run MySQL once installed on mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I have installed MySQL package and started MySQL from the preferences pane, open up terminal and typed sql --help and it doesn't know that MySQL is there: ~bash bad command.
Do I have to change some reference ? 
Also is there a place to enter the password when you first start up as nothing has happened that I can see. I have tried the sql -u root -p; and it doesn't recognise the command.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the client called 'mysql' rather than 'sql'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the mysql client binary - it'll put you in a different "shell" where you can type in your SQL.

Comment: Open Terminal, go to where mysql is installed, and run from there, or look around for GUI applications.